# JAX-WS - Out of memory?

Tags: log4j, jax-ws

i call a simple endpoint-method from client.

```
MyStatus getStatus(Car car) throws NoSuchCarException;
```

what i got is:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:317)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:146)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:129)
at $Proxy124.getStatus(Unknown Source)
at de.Babs.showState(Babs.java:622)
```

What is the problem?
How can i activate xml-logging from JAX comunication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be that there are two many applications deployed into your container or application server. `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` is more due to system's limitation (memory) rather than due to programming mistakes. For e.g. it could mean that there is not enough memory for some resources to be loaded. Make sure you restart your server after each deployment or redeployment.

To enable logging just put needed `log4j` or `slf4j` or whatever framework you are using to server 's global libraries, then create a `log4j.properties` file like this (if you're using `log4j`):

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %X{file} %c{1} - %m%n

####################### YourService ######################
log4j.logger.com.yourservice.servicename=DEBUG,servicename
log4j.additivity.com.yourservice.servicename=false
log4j.logger.servicename=DEBUG,servicename
log4j.additivity.servicename=false
log4j.appender.servicename=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.servicename.File=C:\\Servers\\glassfish-3.1.2\\gf-app-logs\\servicename.log
log4j.appender.servicename.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.servicename.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.servicename.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %X{file} %c{1} %m%n
log4j.appender.servicename.ImmediateFlush=true
########################################################
```

I was using glassfish 3, all the logging appeared in this file: `C:\\Servers\\glassfish-3.1.2\\gf-app-logs\\servicename.log`. For e.g. in glassfish 3, this `log4j.properties` file, needs to be added into: `&{base.dir}\glassfish-3.1.2\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\config`